# Why does `\the\le` typeset `12820`?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, primitives

[TeX primitives reference](https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#the-rp) says that the primivite `\the` can

- typeset a parameter value (integer, dimen, glue, or muglue) or internal quantity (except \font)
- produce a copy of the token list for a token parameter

`\the\le` typesets `12820` and `\the\ge` typesets `12821`.

Does this mean that `\le` is a parameter value or internal quantity, or is this behaviour related to the math-mode definition of `\le` as `\mathchar"3214`?

Comment: `\le` is defined as `\mathchar"3214`  (which in decimals is `12820`) by using `\mathchardef`.  As explained e.g. in https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#mathchardef-rp, control sequences defined by `\mathchardef` can be used with `\the`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the definition of ⟨internal quantity⟩, which you find as the solution of exercise 24.7 (page 336)

⟨internal quantity⟩ → ⟨internal integer⟩ | ⟨internal dimen⟩
      | ⟨internal glue⟩ | ⟨internal muglue⟩ | ⟨internal nonnumeric⟩

Now let's find the definition of ⟨internal integer⟩, which is on page 271:

⟨internal integer⟩ → ⟨integer parameter⟩ | ⟨special integer⟩ | `\lastpenalty`
      | ⟨countdef token⟩ | `\count`⟨8-bit number⟩ | ⟨codename⟩⟨8-bit number⟩
      | ⟨chardef token⟩ | ⟨mathchardef token⟩ | `\parshape` | `\inputlineno`
      | `\hyphenchar`⟨font⟩ | `\skewchar`⟨font⟩ | `\badness`

Finally, `\le` is a ⟨mathchardef token⟩: in `plain.tex` we find

```
\mathchardef\leq="3214 \let\le=\leq
```

and an equivalent definition is found in `fontmath.ltx`, namely

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leq}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"14}
```

---

At some point in the development of TeX, Knuth realized that `\chardef` and `\mathchardef` tokens could be used as integer constants, so not to waste precious counter registers, So the ability of using such tokens when an integer is required by the syntax was added.

For instance the constant 10000 is stored in `plain.tex` as `\@M`, which is defined by

```
\mathchardef\@M=10000
```

which saves four or five tokens each time that `\penalty\@M` is inside a definition.